# Including a CMake-required library in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

Specifically, I have this library https://github.com/PeterJohnson/ntcore

I need to import it to a Qt project and use the features. It features a gradle or a CMake option and I was trying to use the CMakeLists.txt but I couldn't figure out how to add that to the .pro to compile and deploy along with the Qt project itself... any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix `CMake` and `qmake` projects just like that.

I think your realistic options are (ignoring any possible license issues):

1) Change your project to use `CMake` instead of `qmake`. Then it would be simple to include `ntcore` as a sub-build and link to it

2) Pre-compile `ntcore` using `CMake` and use the library and headers only in your `qmake` project